# How to grant ognl.OgnlInvokePermission to whole codebase?

Tags: java, struts2, ognl, ibm-was

We are using IBM WAS6.1 to deploy our Struts2 application,
however every time we try to access a bean we get error like below.
Adding the specific permission in WAS.POLICY file resolves the issue.
But we don't want add hundreds of permission entries in our WAS.POLICY file.
We also tried adding * wildcard WAS.POLICY but apparently our server admins have disabled use of wildcard.

```
permission ognl.OgnlInvokePermission  "invoke.com.cisco.gpe.isecure.p2p.bean.P2PVO.*";
```

The aboove doesn't work and we still get errors like below

```
Permission:invoke.java.util.ArrayList.isEmpty : Access denied (ognl.OgnlInvokePermission invoke.java.util.ArrayList.isEmpty)


Code: ognl.OgnlRuntime  in  {file:/opt/httpd/root/apps/isecur/ibm/ccix-dev-ear/myapp.war/WEB-INF/lib/ognl-3.0.6.jar}

Stack Trace: java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (ognl.OgnlInvokePermission invoke.java.util.ArrayList.isEmpty)
```

**EDIT:** We are using Struts 2.3.16, JDK1.5, Websphere 6.1 32 bit

Comment: I have added the version details in question.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions should be declared in the following way

> "invoke.<declaring-class>.<method-name>"

The `<method-name>` should be a valid name of the method that you can get using `Method.getName()`. It is used as a key to the permissions cache by the OGNL Runtime.

The permission that is not accessible is on class `java.util.ArrayList` and method name `isEmpty`. Then you can declare a permission

```
permission ognl.OgnlInvokePermission  "invoke.java.util.ArrayList.isEmpty"
```

Comment: Thanks Roman for your response, I want avoid individuals permission entries. How can I grant permission to everything that is accessible via my codebase ?

Comment: This is a different question you should check out your `server.policy` file.

Comment: Have you got an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
permission ognl.OgnlInvokePermission  "invoke.*";
```

but that could be too broad and insecure, defeating the purpose of using security manager.

Struts2 is prone to ognl injection, after testing struts2 with some exploit tool, found that the following are exploited, there may be more. 
"invoke.java.lang.Object.getClass", "invoke.java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start", "invoke.java.lang.ProcessBuilder.redirectErrorStream",  "invoke.java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime", "invoke.org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter".